# How to correctly configure my stackview?

Tags: ios, autolayout, storyboard, uistackview

I drag a vertical UIStackView in my storyboard, I constrain it vertically and horizontally and give it fixed dimensions, 300x300.

Inside this stackview, I put:

1. a UIImageView (Aspect Fit)
2. an horizontal stackview containing two buttons

I have no problems if I equally space the content inside the main stackview, but it's not what I want.

I want the imageview to take 70% of the vertical space, leaving the other 30% to the buttons.

[image: This should be the result]

I tried using `Fill proportionally` on the main stackview, but, while in the storyboard is anything ok, when I test on simulator the two buttons totally disappear and I only see the imageview with its content.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[I've recorded a short video](https://www.dropbox.com/s/s5hug5lif0ezr19/stackoverflow_40870551.mov?dl=0)

Basically you need to set the height of the image to be equal to 70% of the stackview height. Hope it'd help

Comment: Ok, even if your quite perfect video (THANKS very much) doesn't show it, I found a strange thing basicly thanks to you: I tried your solution and finally found the main stackview must use "Fill", not "Fill proportionally". This way it works with no errors